# git how to revert to specific revision

Tags: directory, git-revert

I have a git project.
I just made a commit, then I deleted some directories. ops, my bad.
Now I want to restore those directories that I have deleted. how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This command will discard any working copy changes you have made since the last commit.

Comment: +1: also, user281521, note that you can do "git log" and get the revision you want, and put that in place of "HEAD"

Comment: Before try "git reset --hard HEAD", trough "git log" I try to checkout my latest revision, but nothing changes. when I run "git reset --hard HEAD", the project reverted to the revision BEFORE the HEAD, before the one I did just before delete the directories. And I got the message "HEAD is now at f3f34f3 bla" (bla was my revision).